# Why isn't my TextView displaying its string properly?

Tags: java, android

I'm using an example out of the android programming book I'm going through. The point of this exercise is that when I click the "about" button, a new activity should start and display some text. For some reason that text is not showing up even though the text shows up in the graphical layout in my IDE. I'm using my phone as the emulator and my phone is running Android 4.0.3. I'm using eclipse. Here's my code:

Main activity:

```
package org.example.sodoku;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Sudoku extends Activity implements OnClickListener   {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        View continueButton= findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
        continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View newButton= findViewById(R.id.new_button);
        newButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View aboutButton= findViewById(R.id.about_button);
        aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        View exitButton= findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.about_button:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Main xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@color/background"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:padding="35dip">
   <TextView
      android:text="@string/main_title"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
      android:textSize="24.5sp" />
   <TableLayout
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:stretchColumns="*">
      <TableRow>
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/continue_button"
            android:text="@string/continue_label" />
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_button"
            android:text="@string/new_game_label" />
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/about_button"
            android:text="@string/about_label" />
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/exit_button"
            android:text="@string/exit_label" />
      </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

About Class:

```
package org.example.sodoku;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class About extends Activity {
    protected void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);





    }

}
```

About xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dip">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/about_text" >
</TextView>


    </ScrollView>
```

[EDIT] Forgot about strings xml and manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="hello">Hello World, Sudoku!</string>
    <string name="app_name">Sudoku</string>
    <string name="main_title">Android Sodoku</string>
    <string name="continue_label">Continue</string>
    <string name="new_game_label">New Game</string>
    <string name="about_label">About</string>
    <color name="background">#3500ffff</color>
    <string name="exit_label">Exit</string>
    <string name="about_title">About Android Sudoku</string>
    <string name="about_text">fuck your ethnicity</string>
</resources>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.example.sodoku"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Sudoku"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".About"
            android:label="@string/about_title">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is the value of the string "about_text" (which I assume is in your res/values/strings.xml)?

Comment: note the capital `A` in `Amount.xml` [if that is how you named it in your project]. your java code has `amount.xml`

Comment: Did you add the About.class in the manifest file?  Are there any errors in the LogCat?

Comment: Added strings xml and manifest.

Comment: One thing that could be the problem that you guys could look at is the android version and SDK. I'm targeting 2.3 with minimum SDK 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have misspelled `onCreate()` method in your About activity (compare `OnCreate()`and `onCreate()`), so you don't actually override base class method. Replace your onCreate with this one:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may help you. use this one as about.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/about_text" >
   </TextView>

   </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What difference will putting it in a LinearLayout make? Can't a ScrollView display a TextView by itself? (honest question)

Comment: @matt5784 there should be no difference AFAIK